# Is realm a relational database?

Tags: java, android, database, realm

I have tried searching about Realm but following questions were not answered. Please help me to understand the following questions properly: 
Is realm a relational database? 
How is it more efficient as compared to SQLite?

Answer (score 19):

NO, Realm is **not** a relational database.

It allows you to declare *relationships* between objects the same as you would do in any object graph in your language of choice.

[JP's talk on the core](https://realm.io/news/jp-simard-realm-core-database-engine/) describes it in more detail and is highly recommended.

It stores objects in an optimal memory-mapped format, using *column-store* techniques for fast searching. Accessors in the different language SDKs map directly to functions using that memory-mapped storage.

In contrast, anything using a relational database like SQLite has multiple layers of copying buffers.

Note: I was on the Realm Xamarin team (2015-2017), left a great bunch of people after we shipped v1.0 to focus on my own startup.

Comment: Object Oriented DataBase Management System: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_database

Comment: Realm backend is based on LMDB? Is it open source like forntends?

Comment: Realm has its own C++ core. It does not use any code from LMDB. The core was originally kept private but released as open source in 2016 https://github.com/realm/realm-core

Answer (score -10):

Yes, realm is a **relational database**. Much faster when complex queries are fired. Supports less number of programming languages.

http://db-engines.com/en/system/Realm%3BSQLite